# Correct Boltzmann counting for the partition function for diatomic molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

Would it be reasonable, given the following:

[image: K. Huang 7.2 page 167]

to use a factor of $\frac{1}{2^N N!}$ as opposed to the standard $\frac{1}{ N!}$ for the correct Boltzmann counting term in the partition function for the system given that we can assume that the two particles in the diatomic molecule are indistinguishable?

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be reasonable... to use a factor of $\frac{1}{2^N N!}$ as opposed to the standard $\frac{1}{ N!}$ for the correct Boltzmann counting term in the partition function for the system given that we can assume that the two particles in the diatomic molecule are indistinguishable

No, that doesn't really make sense. If you were treating all 2N particle as indistinguishable, the factor would be $\frac{1}{(2N)!}$. But this is not what to do.

I'm not entirely sure what your true question is... If you are missing a factor of 1/2 in the single particle partition function, it could be from a change of variables. But tough to say without more details of the actual problem you are trying to solve and they work you have done so far.

In general the partition function for a system of N diatomic molecules will be
$$
Z = \frac{z_1^N}{N!}\;,
$$
where
$$
z_1 = \int \frac{d^3 p_1}{(2\pi\hbar)^3} \frac{d^3 p_2}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}
{d^3 r_1}{d^3 r_2}e^{-\beta \mathcal{H}(\vec p_1, \vec p_2, \vec r_1, \vec r_2)}
$$
where
$\mathcal{H}$ is the Hamiltonian you included a picture of in your post.